# Django code for generating SVG belongs in Model or view?

Tags: django, django-models, svg, django-views

I have a long method in my Model that generates an SVG from the model instance.
It creates a Dot graph and then renders it.

Should this code be in a view instead?

Comment: I would create a separate module and class (SVGraphGenerator) just for that and I would render it inside the view based on the informations from the model!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, it should. The model is the description of the data, and holds functionality to add, delete and update records in your datastore. The view describes data that is visible to the user. As you are creating data to be presented to your users, I'd say this better fits the view. This is most in line with what the [Django FAQ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names) says. But, to quote the conclusion of the linked FAQ entry, *"At the end of the day, of course, it comes down to getting stuff done"*.

Comment: True. Getting stuff done is paramount, but it's nice to think through best practices.